# Scatterplot of two Pandas Series, coloured by date and with legend

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend, series

I am studying financial time series, in the format of pandas series. To compare two series I do a scatterplot, and to visualise the time evolution in the scatterplot I can colour them. This is all fine.

My question relates to the legend showing the colours.
I would like the legend to show the date/year that the colour corresponds to, rather than just an the index of the data entry, as now. But I haven't been able to do this, or to find a question like this on stackoverflow.

I know the time series knows the dates, and if you just plot a time series, the x-axis will show the dates.

My code is

```
from pandas_datareader import data as web
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#Download data
start = '2010-1-1'
end = '2016-10-1'
AAPL = web.DataReader('AAPL', 'yahoo', start=start, end=end)['Adj Close']
TSLA = web.DataReader('GOOG', 'yahoo', start=start, end=end)['Adj Close']

#Scatterplot
plt.scatter(AAPL, TSLA, alpha=.4, c=range(len(AAPL)))
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("AAPL")
plt.ylabel("TSLA")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

This code produces this plot:
[Scatterplot with colours and legend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjU2w.png)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Minor nitpick: I think the word you're looking for is colorbar, not legend. A legend is normally used to denote a box overlay that labels and explains different datasets plotted together on the same plot.

Answer (score 4):

While there might be an easier answer out there (anyone?), to me the most straightforward way is to change the colorbar ticks manually.

Try the following before you invoke `plt.show()`:

```
clb = plt.gci().colorbar # get the colorbar artist
# get the old tick labels (index numbers of the dataframes)
clb_ticks = [int(t.get_text()) for t in clb.ax.yaxis.get_ticklabels()]
# convert the old, index, ticks into year-month-day format
new_ticks = AAPL.index[clb_ticks].strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
clb.ax.yaxis.set_ticklabels(new_ticks)
```

Note that `strftime` does not appear to be implemented in `pandas` versions older than `0.18`. In that case you'll have to replace `.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` with `.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))` as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738169/convert-column-of-date-objects-in-pandas-dataframe-to-strings).

[image: clb-ymd_labels-pandas]

Comment: If you think the answer was helpful and informative, consider following the stackoverflow [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), marking it as accepted.