# Is there a way to change the date format for all the dates in my table?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I know there are many questions and answers about date format in a data frame, but I was quite able to find the answer to my question.

I got a data frame with a date format like this: "Tue, Oct 22, 2019". However, I would like to try and convert it into this format : %Y-%m-%d.

Here's what I tried :

```
nba_score['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(nba_score['Date'],format="%a %b %d %Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

But I receive this error : `ValueError: time data 'Tue, Oct 22, 2019' does not match format '%a %b %d %Y' (match)`

Then I tried to add commas to reflect the right format like this:

```
nba_score['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(nba_score['Date'],format="%a, %b %d, %Y").strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

And I receive this error: AttributeError: `'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `dt.strftime`, prefix with dt accesor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this answer: [Convert column of date objects in Pandas DataFrame to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738169/convert-column-of-date-objects-in-pandas-dataframe-to-strings). You need to add `.dt` before `.strftime`.

Use:

```
nba_score['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(nba_score['Date'],format="%a, %b %d, %Y").dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```