# How do I convert date format in a column in a csv file using pandas in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date-formatting

I have a a csv file called "amazon_responded.csv" in which I am currently trying to format the dates in one of the columns in the file.

[image]

I need to format this date column called "tweet_created_at" into the format of "Nov 01". Ultimately I need to group the data by day, but I cant figure out how to format the date column into the format of "Nov 01".

I have tried using pd.to_datetime but i just can crack the right format.

Answer (score 0):

You want to convert it into `Nov 01` format because you want to group them by this right?

You can do it without formatting also.

by:

```
df['tweet_created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tweet_created_at'])
```

Groupby Day and month:

`df.groupby([df['tweet_created_at'].day, df['tweet_created_at'].month])`

If you want to convert them into `Nov 01` form:

```
df['new_date'] = df['tweet_created_at'].strftime('%b') + ' ' + df['tweet_created_at'].strftime('%d')
```

---

sample code:

```
st = "Tue Nov 01 01:57:25 +0000 2016"

st = pd.to_datetime(st)
date = st.strftime('%b') + ' ' + st.strftime('%d')
```

---

**date:**

```
'Nov 01'
```

Comment: Any idea as to why i am getting an error: " 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime' " ?

Comment: @Marceloo: try using `dt`  https://stackoverflow.com/a/33967346/6660373

Answer (score 0):

After you use `pd.to_datetime()` method just do this:-

```
df['tweet_created_at']=df['tweet_created_at'].apply(lambda x:x.ctime().split(' '))
df['tweet_created_at']=df['tweet_created_at'].apply(lambda x:' '.join([x[1],x[3]]))
```