# Pandas, removing timestamp from datetime column using dt.date or dt.strftime converts column to dtype: object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

Example df of how my data is stored:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'DOB': {0: '2003-01-01 00:00:00+00', 1: '2003-01-02 00:00:00+00'}})
```

I want to convert the column to datetime, and only keep the Year-Month-Day values. Basically, exactly as this question:

[Removing the timestamp from a datetime in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858155/removing-the-timestamp-from-a-datetime-in-pandas-dataframe)

and this one:

[Convert column of date objects in Pandas DataFrame to strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738169/convert-column-of-date-objects-in-pandas-dataframe-to-strings)

Except using these answer, extracting the dates from the column which is already a Datetime format converts the column to an Object format. This is also discussed in the comments, but seems to have been moved to chat which isn't available anymore.

Result in first answer:

```
[in] pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.date
[out]
0    2003-01-01
1    2003-01-02
Name: DOB, dtype: object
```

Result of second answer:

```
[in] pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
[out] 
0    2003-01-01
1    2003-01-02
Name: DOB, dtype: object
```

As you can see, it's not a Datetime format anymore but an object. Then I can't use it furthermore in my script.

Using the `format = "%Y-%m-%d` option of pd.to_datetime doesn't work too, as the timestamp is still present:

```
[in] pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
[out] 
0   2003-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
1   2003-01-02 00:00:00+00:00
Name: DOB, dtype: datetime64[ns, UTC]
```

What is a simple solution to make sure the column stays in a datetime format, while only keeping the date as format?

Comment: what type do you want? object doesn't mean anything specific

Comment: I want the column to be in datetime format. Like the bottom section of code is showing, but without the timestamp.

Comment: Then what is wrong with `pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.date`? This will give you a `datetime.date`

Comment: It doesn't give a datetime, it returns as ```dtype: object``` . That's the 1st answers issue.

Comment: This is just a representation, the real type is `datetime.date`: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71141043/16343464). You actually have the same thing with many other types

Comment: I'm getting constant issues when performing simple functions using datetime on this column though this way, and not when it's a datetime format.

Comment: Maybe this is the real question you should ask ;)

Comment: Maybe it is! But all of my issues were solved once this column is just a datetime, and removes later on a lot of code dealing with this issue. That's why I was hoping there was a solution before dealing with it.

Comment: Note that there is a difference between the datetime type pandas uses and native Python datetime. While Python has a date type, pandas does not. With pandas datetime you always have date ***and*** time. If you switch to native Python's date type (`.dt.date`), you loose a lot of functionality.

Comment: Yes the types are different (this is why pandas displays 'object' as it is not native). I guess this might be the issue, but for that a clear example should be provided (maybe in a fresh question)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMO there is no issue here:

```
s = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(['2021-02-01 00:00:00']))
s
# 0   2021-02-01
# dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And indeed, the **displayed** type is "object":

```
s.dt.date
# 0    2021-02-01
# dtype: object
```

But this doesn't mean much, the type is really `datetime.date`:

```
type(s.dt.date[0])
# datetime.date
```

Comment: I'm getting constant issues when performing simple functions using datetime on this column though this way, and not when it's a datetime format.

Answer (score 0):

I have it working with two extra lines, but was hoping there would be a simpler solution to this issue:

```
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])
df['DOB'] = DF['DOB'].dt.date
df['DOB'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])

# gives
[in] df
[out]
0    2003-01-01
1    2003-01-02
Name: DOB, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: You could just floor to the day `.dt.floor('d')`

Comment: That still adds the timestamp in seconds too.

Comment: your code has them too at the end, they're just not *displayed*.

Comment: what your code actually does differently is strip the tzinfo (UTC). You can do that more conveniently as well, by localizing to None; `pd.to_datetime(df['DOB']).dt.floor('d').dt.tz_localize(None)` in one line.